# Inheritance of friendliness and access levels

Tags: c++

I have a following quiz problem:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct A
{
    void ohai() { cout  << "ohai" << endl; }
};

struct C : private A {
    friend int main();
};

struct X : C {};
struct Y : private C {};

int main() {    
    C().ohai()  // OK
    X().ohai(); // OK
    Y().ohai(); // Not OK
}
```

The thing is that class C inherits from A privately. So, all members of A, even public, now become private in C. 
Class C also declares friendliness with the main function (this is OK, now the 'main' function can call private methods of C).
Then there are classes X and Y, both derived from C.
X derives from C publicly, Y derives from C privately.

In the 'main' function I create instance of Class C and call the 'ohai' method inherited privately from A, this works fine, since main is a friend of C.
Then I create instance of class X and call 'ohai' - this surprisingly works!
But when I create instance of class Y this does not work!

I know that inheritance is NOT INHERITABLE. So this is not the inheriting of friendliness which allows 'main' to call 'ohai' method on an object of class X.
The thing with class Y confirms that, since it is enough to change the type of inheritance to private to stop this working.

I wonder why it is OK to call 'ohai' on X object. Inheriting cannot bump up the level of the function (from private to public), so if X inherits from C, even publicly, all private methods from C should remain private in X. And since friendliness is not inheritable the 'main' method should not be able to call private method of X. 
Class Y inherits privately from C, and this makes all members of C be private in X, but the 'ohai' method was already private in C (since C inherited privately from A) so this should not change anythig, but somehow it does (compared to X).

Please help me understand this issue.
Best Regards
YotKay

Answer (score 1):

I am not entirely sure about my answer here. Please correct me if I am wrong.

What I believe what happens here is that when you call `X().ohai()`, the `this` pointer in `X` is implicitly casted to its base class `C`, which granted friendship to `main`. More precisely, when the compiler look for `ohai` in `X`, it does not find it in `X`, nor its immediate base class `C`, instead it find it in `A`. The friendship and other access control mechanism does not interfere where the compiler should find a member function. Its effect comes after the member is found. Once the compiler found `ohai` in `A`, it need to cast a `X *` pointer (`this`) to `A *`. (Up to this point, I am pretty sure I am correct). `X` is public inherited from `C`, so it can cast it to `C *`. And `C` give `main` friendship, so it can continue to cast it to `A *`. And thus it is able to call `ohai`. (The last part is not very precise, but easier for understanding).

For example, try the following,

```
int main()
{
    X x;
    Y y;
    static_cast<A *>(&x);
    static_cast<A *>(&y);
}
```

The first cast will have no problem, while the second cast will give you the following error in Clang,

```
test.cpp:24:22: error: cannot cast 'Y' to its private base class 'A'
    static_cast<A *>(&y);
                     ^
test.cpp:15:11: note: constrained by private inheritance here
class Y : private C
          ^~~~~~~~~
```

If you remove the `friend` declaration, the first cast will also fail, but for a different reason.

"friendship cannot be inherited" is correct but it actually does not have anything to do with what happened here

If you remove the friend declaration, and try the following,

```
int main()
{
    X x;
    Y y;
    static_cast<A *>(&x);
    static_cast<C *>(&x);
}
```

The first cast will fail due to access control, while the second will success.

The friendship to main not only grant its access to `C`'s private members, but also its private base class. For this matter, try the following with and without the friend declaration

```
int main()
{
    C c;
    static_cast<A *>(&c);
}
```

Last, try the following

```
struct A {
    void ohai() { std::cout << "ohai" << std::endl; }
};

struct C : private A {
    using A::ohai;
};

struct X : C {
    void foo() { C::ohai(); } // static_cast<C *>(this)->ohai();
    void bar() { A::ohai(); } // static_cast<A *>(this)->ohai();
};

int main()
{
    X x;
    x.foo();
    x.bar();
    x.ohai();
}
```

The function `foo` will be OK but `bar` will fail. Because `X` can be casted to its immediate base `C` and call the `ohai` made public in `C`. But it cannot be cased to `A` and call the `ohai` in `A`

Comment: Thank you. Maybe you are right. I tried your examples and in case of example (1) in GCC I got the same error in both cases ("error: 'A' is an inaccessible base of 'X'"), with and without friendliness declaration (contrary to Clang, according to what you wrote). In the second example it is as you wrote, the first cast fails with the same error as above, the second one works fine.

Comment: @YotKay Just "maybe" Don't be too sure about my answer. I think it can explain what happened. But I did not find specific phrases in the standard after the point where I said *Up to this point, I am pretty sure I am correct*. Given time others more informed might give you better answer

Comment: @YotKay Access control comes after resolving member function call, and member function call will involve implicit cast to base class, this much is clear though.

Comment: Any other answer?